# Can't download Xcode Beta 3 without Apple Developer membership

Tags: xcode

Prior to this, one could easily download Xcode Beta from [Apple Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/) with only their Apple ID. There was no need for Apple Developer membership. (I downloaded Xcode 7 Beta 1 without any problems.) But now that Xcode 7 Beta 3 is released, after I click the download button and sign in using my Apple ID, [this page](https://developer.apple.com/unauthorized/).

I'm not aware of any announcements regarding this issue. Is there some kind of bug involved or Apple limited the access to Xcode Beta for registered developers?

Comment: I've had this problem too. Have you contacted Apple?

Comment: Did you do as the message says (agree to updated license)?

Comment: @patrix How can I do that? I headed to the Member Center but didn't see anything about agreeing to updated license.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that as well, sorry. Would try again tomorrow or contact Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is resolved. I can download Xcode Beta from Apple Developer website.